# How to allow only a certain type of foreign key in a table

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraint, best-practices

I'm designing a new DB. I have `employee` and `order` table. `order` table has `deliverer_id` to indicate who delivered the order. But only `employee` who is "deliverer" should be allowed.

I thought of 3 methods to enforce this.

- Create `deliverer` table in the middle of `employee` and `order` tables to make use of foreign key restrictions: But if I choose this method, I might need to make many other tables like `administrator`, `supervisor`, `guest` and so on for other tables. I fear if this makes things harder unnecessarily. This would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1_employee
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1_deliverer
(
    employee_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT temp_deliverer_temp_employee_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES temp1_employee (id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1_order
(
    id           INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    deliverer_id INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT temp_order_temp_deliverer_employee_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (deliverer_id) REFERENCES temp1_deliverer (employee_id)
);
```

- Add `type` column in `employee` table and create a trigger on `order` table to check if the `employee.type` is "deliverer": I'm worried about this method since I read that triggers should be used carefully or even avoided if possible.
- Since this is a business logic(is it?), it should be enforced from applications: But I already know those applications will cause a lot of trouble if it's not enforced by DBMS.

Which method should be used? Maybe there is another?

Answer (score 1):

Possible realization.

1. Main table

   > ```
   > CREATE TABLE main ( id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 
   >                     type VARCHAR(16)
   >                   );
   > ```
2. Prepare main table for referencing

   > ```
   > ALTER TABLE main 
   >     ADD COLUMN for_reference INT UNSIGNED AS (CASE WHEN type LIKE 'allowed%' THEN id END) STORED,
   >     ADD UNIQUE key_for_reference (for_reference);
   > ```
3. Create referenced table

   > ```
   > CREATE TABLE slave ( id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   >                      reference INT UNSIGNED,
   >                      CONSTRAINT fk_to_main FOREIGN KEY (reference) REFERENCES main (for_reference)
   >                    );
   > ```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2b53431a8a596122e90f6f1c8f4ac80)

PS. Pay attention - the field in main table which is used for referencing primarily (`id`) must be unique but NOT autoincremented (because the expression of generated column cannot refer to AI). In general this field must be unique but not primary key.